# Mongoose : error returned is empty object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, error-handling

what am I doing wrong?
Try to save a new Entry via findOneAndUpdate.

```
Offer.findOneAndUpdate(conditions,payload,{upsert:true,new: true},function(err, offer) {
    if(err){
            response.status(500).send({"message": "This is an error! Can not save _offer", "error":err, "payload":payload});
    }else{
            response.status(200).send(offer);
    }
});
```

but I got permanently Error 500 with error = {}

> {"message":"This is an error! Can not save
>   _offer","error":{},"payload":{"foo":"bar"}}

What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

Found the Problem : conditions doesn't met schema :/ nevertheless bad behavior from mongo/mongoose

Error : {}

```
var conditions = {
 foo: bar
};
```

Solution :

```
var conditions = {
 foo: new ObjectId(bar._id)
};
```

Need to refer on ObjectId instead on Object

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if Mongoose provide us with "findoneandupdate" you got

```
.save()
```

Instead you can try this code:

```
Model.findOne({ name: 'bourne' }, function (err, doc){
  doc.name = 'jason bourne';
  doc.visits.$inc();
  doc.save();
});
```

Here is the link to [Docs.](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html)

Try this if it doesn't work, please specify the conditions and payload.